# Union doesn't print right values in C

Tags: c, unions

When I execute this program it doesn't print back what I inputed into it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

union integer{
      char c;
      short s;
      int i;
      long b;
      };

int main( void )
{
    union integer aInteger;

    printf( "Enter a char: " );   
    scanf( "%c", &aInteger.c );
    printf( "\nEnter a short: " );
    scanf( "%hd", &aInteger.s );
    printf( "\nEnter a int: " );
    scanf( "%d", &aInteger.i );
    printf( "\nEnter a long: " );
    scanf( "%ld", &aInteger.b );

    printf( "\nChar: %c\nShort: %hd\nInt: %d\nLong: %ld",
            aInteger.c, aInteger.s, aInteger.i, aInteger.b );

    getche();
    return 0;
}
```

I entered A, 12, 1234 and 123456789 as input and the results were a character that looked like a unknown of shape Z from pokemon, -13035, 123456789 and 123456789.I expected that this program would print back what I inputted.Is it because I am referencing all the members of the union by assigning values
to all of them ? What should I change so it can print back the input using a union not a structure ?

Comment: use `struct` instead of `union`.

Comment: By using a union you are using the same memory space for **all** the variables. If you use a struct as @BLUEPIXY mentions, each variable will have its own memory space.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add: (1) your input; (2) your current output; (3) **very** important! what you expect it to write. As it is, the program does exactly what you are telling it to do but you seem to expect something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From "The C programming language" by Kernighan and Ritchie:

> **6.8 UNIONS**
>   A *union* is a variable that may hold (at different times) objects of different types and sizes, with the compiler keeping track of size and alignment requirements.

The key phrase is "at different times". Every write operation to one of its elements changes the value of the other members as well, because the elements themselves *overlap* in memory.

At the time of printing your output, all results of write operations before the last one are discarded. (Not by definition; your last write operation merely wrote the largest amount data. Whether or not a *shorter* amount of data would have overwritten all, or parts of, the other elements, depends on the sizes of `char` and `short` of your compiler.)

If you feel you *must* use a `union` instead of a `struct`, you must make sure you cannot overwrite "old" data with "new". This requires you to know the size of your basic types, and you must make each element an array with the total length of your *largest* element - *and* reserve enough space for the vlaue of the largest element as well:

```
union integer {
      char c[2*sizeof(long)/sizeof(char)];
      short s[2*sizeof(long)/sizeof(short)];
      int i[2*sizeof(int)/sizeof(long)];
      long b[2];
      };
```

This assumes all of the larger sizes are a multiple of the smaller ones, i.e., it will not work when (imaginably) `sizeof(short)` is 3 but `sizeof(int)` is 4.

Now you can read from and write to `aInteger.c[0]`, `aInteger.s[1]`, `aInteger.i[2]`, and `aInteger.b[1]` without overwriting any others' "important" data.

I may have some of the indexes wrong here. Then again, I don't feel like testing this as it is a purely academical question, and in reality you should either simply use a regular `struct`, or build up the union elements from `structs`.